# template string with ng-if has Error: $parse:syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a string

```
const notes ="some notes"
```

Below is the notes template string

```
const notesTemplate = `<span ng-if="${notes} !=''">${notes}</span>`
```

In the above statement im getting the error

> angular.js:12609 Error: $parse:syntax 
>      http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=vdsdsf&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=4&p3=vf%20vdsdsf%20!%3D%3D%27%27&p4=vdsdsf%20!%3D%3D

I dont understand where im going wrong, any help would be appreciated

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Are you trying to bind this to the template? `ng-if` will not render when added dynamically to your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're introducing the variable in the template string it needs to be in quotes, follow the [error URL](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$parse/syntax?p0=vdsdsf&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=4&p3=vf%20vdsdsf%20!%3D%3D''&p4=vdsdsf%20!%3D%3D) it makes things much clearer. Your template string could be as follows:

```js
const notesTemplate = `<span ng-if= "'${notes}' != ''">${notes}</span>`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code .

```
const notesTemplate = <span  ng-if="notes">${notes}</span>
```

Hope it gets helpful to you .

Comment: He is using angularJS Version 1.4.8, not Angular >= 2. Also it would be *ngIf with an uppercase 'i'

Comment: check my updated answer @StefanRein . And in previous answer if was by-mistake in `*ngIf` with lowercase `i`.

Comment: Was that helpful ? @StefanRein